# Where can I find the list of web scraping projects to practice?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am looking to practice the web scraping projects. Can anyone tell me where can I find such list or give me some examples of web scraping projects?

Comment: youtube have some playlists

Answer (score 0):

Scraping is a broad term, you need to be more specific to get a detailed answer.

But take a look here:
http://google-rank-checker.squabbel.com/
Contains a lot of information and open source scraping code.

It's focused on Google and Bing but the information is quite universal and the code useful in any case.